# How to get value in json response

Tags: android, json

I need get the value elements in response api post, I receive the answer as a json, below are the example:

```
public void postJsonToServer() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject js = createJsonObject();
        String url = "http://link/User";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url, js, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    String as = response.getString("Planta");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Response:

```
{"Codigo":200,"Mensaje":"Usuario validado","Nombre":"Luis Smith","ClaveNom":"9633","Planta":"SIN","Indicador":"","Listado":""}
```

How to get element Planta, and Indicador?

the next line returns null and I don't know what else to do, help me please.

```
 String as = response.getString("Planta");
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
try {
   JSONObject responseOBJ = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
   if(responseOBJ.has(responseOBJ.getString("Planta"))
   {
     String as = responseOBJ.getString("Planta");
   }
   
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```